# Strange lock screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

i am getting strange lock screen on ubuntu 20.04 from last couple of days. icons on lock screen panel (on top right side) are black, unproportionate size , same as other text/icons on lock screen.  Even after login, top panel icons are black and unproportionate. After login also, i am unbale to perform normal work.

As i workaround, either im restarting gdm3 or system itself.
PLease see screen shots.

Any idea whats going on?

[image: Lock Screen]

[image: After Login, See top panel]

Comment: Did you try to customize theme??

Comment: no, Its Yaru now.

Comment: Ok.. Whats the output of `update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource` command in the terminal

Comment: There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm3-theme.gresource (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource).

  Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource              10        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        manual mode

Press ....

Comment: Ok choose 1 and reboot to check only login screen..

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Logon screen is not proper or lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me when i installed `lubuntu-desktop` alongside gnome on ubuntu 20.04 . I configured it `lightdm` as the default display manager to run on boot
It showed me  a strange lock and login screen and it was almost impossible to type password from my physical keyboard so I had to use the useless screen keyboard .
try reinstalling ubuntu desktop
steps :

1. boot into recovery mode and run the following  commands:
    `sudo apt update`
   `sudo apt autoremove ubuntu-desktop`
    `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`
   note that: set the display manager to gdm3

Comment: i have not installed any additional desktop env and using default env which comes with ubuntu 20.04

Comment: thanks, i have re-installed  ubuntu-desktop and so far have not faced this issue.

Comment: You are welcome